# Как через pywinauto нажать на специфический toggle, в настройках приватности Win 10(камера)?

Tags: python-3.x, test-automation, pywinauto

Этот toggle не видит dump_tree() или print_control_identifiers(), но видит Inspect.exe. Как на него нажать?
[image: Toggle]

````
from pywinauto import Application
from pywinauto import keyboard
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys, KeySequenceError
import time
import os
import pyautogui

os.system(r"Settings_lanch.bat")  
# Inside Settings_lanch.bat only:  start ms-settings:privacy
time.sleep(1)
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title=u"Параметры")
# app.Параметры.dump_tree()  # print identifiers for further automation
app.Параметры.set_focus()

appik = Application().connect(title="Параметры")
window = appik.ApplicationFrameWindow
window.set_focus()
window.maximize()

small_time = 0.3
skroll_time = 0.01

Cameracontroll = app.Параметры.child_window(title="Камера", auto_id="SettingsPagePrivacyWebcam", control_type="ListItem").wrapper_object()
Cameracontroll.click_input()
Cameracontroll.set_focus()
OKdata = app.Параметры.child_window(title="Изменить", control_type="Button")
OKdata.click_input()

# нажал на кнопку, а вот как дальше взаимодействовать с Toggle???

# все что ниже, это варианты, которые я перепробовал, чтобы переключить этот Toggle в неактивное состояние,
# и у меня это так и не получилось!

# app.Параметры.OK.click()
# app.Параметры.Доступккамередляэтогоустройства.click()
# app.Доступккамередляэтогоустройства.click()
# OKdata = app.Параметры.child_window(title="Изменить", auto_id="SystemSettings_CapabilityAccess_Camera_SystemGlobal_Button", control_type="Button")
# OKdata.click_input()
# app.Параметры.child_window(best_match='Доступ', top_level_only=False).dump_tree()
# app.Параметры.dump_tree()

# OKdata = app.Параметры.child_window(best_match='ToggleSwitch', top_level_only=False)
# OKdata.click_input()
# OKdata.toggle()
# OKdata = app.window(best_match='ToggleSwitch', top_level_only=False).dump_tree()
# OKdata = app.window(best_match='ToggleSwitch', top_level_only=False).print_control_identifiers()
# OKdata.click_input()


# pyautogui.click(x, y)
# pyautogui.press("space")
# time.sleep(small_time)

# pyautogui.keyDown("space")
# time.sleep(small_time)
# pyautogui.keyUp("space")

# pyautogui.keyDown("enter")
# time.sleep(small_time)
# pyautogui.keyUp("enter")
time.sleep(2)

try:
    app.Параметры.type_keys('{TAB}', with_spaces=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
try:
    app.Параметры.send_keys('{TAB}{SPACE}', with_spaces=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
try:
    app.Параметры.type_keys("{TAB}{SPACE}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass

try:
    app.Параметры.send_keystrokes("{VK_SPACE}")
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
try:
    app.Параметры.send_keys('{VK_SPACE}', with_spaces=True)
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
try:
    app.send_keys('{TAB}{SPACE}', with_spaces=True)
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass

# Ничего из этого не помогло
# /--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESULT:
# Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'send_keys' were found (typo?)

# Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'send_keystrokes' were found (typo?)
# Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'send_keys' were found (typo?)
# Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'send_keys' were found (typo?)
# /---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     # INSPECT.EXE (on this button):

"""
How found:  Mouse move (296,247)
    hwnd=0x007003AE 64bit class="Shell_Flyout" style=0x96000000 ex=0x0
RuntimeId:  "[42.7340974.4.5]"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:276 t:191 r:459 b:267}
ProcessId:  3900
ControlType:    UIA_ButtonControlTypeId (0xC350)
LocalizedControlType:   "переключатель"
Name:   "Доступ к камере для этого устройства"
HasKeyboardFocus:   true
IsKeyboardFocusable:    true
IsEnabled:  true
ClassName:  "ToggleSwitch"
ClickablePoint: {x:322 y:251}
Culture:    1049
IsControlElement:   true
IsContentElement:   true
IsPassword: false
IsOffscreen:    false
Orientation:    0
FrameworkId:    "XAML"
IsRequiredForForm:  false
IsDataValidForForm: true
ProviderDescription:    "[pid:3900,providerId:0x0 Main(parent link):Unidentified Provider (unmanaged:Windows.UI.Xaml.dll)]"
Toggle.ToggleState: On (1)
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:   false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:   false
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollPatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:   true
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:    false
IsTablePatternAvailable:    false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:   true
IsTransformPatternAvailable:    false
IsValuePatternAvailable:    false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   false
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:    false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:  false
FirstChild: "Доступ к камере для этого устройства" текст
LastChild:  "" бегунок
Next:   [null]
Previous:   [null]
Other Props:    Object has no additional properties
Children:   "Доступ к камере для этого устройства" текст
    "Откл." текст
    "Вкл." текст
    "" бегунок
Ancestors:  "Доступ к камере для этого устройства" окно
    "Параметры" окно
    "Рабочий стол 1" панель
    [ No Parent ]
"""
# /------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# app.Параметры.dump_tree()   - ее просто не видит!
"""

|    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Если доступ разрешен, любой человек, использующий это устройство, может с помощью параметров на этой странице разрешить или запретить приложениям доступ к камере. Если доступ запрещен, приложения Microsoft Store и большинство классических приложений не смогут использовать камеру. При этом доступ к ней остается у Windows Hello.", auto_id="SystemSettings_CapabilityAccess_Camera_SystemGlobal_Group_GroupDescriptionTextBlock", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Доступ к камере для этого устройства включен'    (L344, T272, R790, B291)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Доступ к камере для этого устройства включен', 'Static37', 'Доступ к камере для этого устройства включенStatic']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Доступ к камере для этого устройства включен", auto_id="SystemSettings_CapabilityAccess_Camera_SystemGlobal_ActionDescriptionTextBlock", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Button - 'Изменить'    (L344, T299, R435, B330)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Изменить', 'Button5', 'ИзменитьButton']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Изменить", auto_id="SystemSettings_CapabilityAccess_Camera_SystemGlobal_Button", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | GroupBox - 'Разрешить приложениям доступ к камере'    (L344, T377, R785, B629)
   |    |    |    | ['GroupBox6', 'Разрешить приложениям доступ к камереGroupBox', 'Разрешить приложениям доступ к камере', 'Разрешить приложениям доступ к камере0', 'Разрешить приложениям доступ к камере1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Разрешить приложениям доступ к камере", control_type="Group")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Разрешить приложениям доступ к камере'    (L344, T377, R785, B404)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Разрешить приложениям доступ к камереStatic', 'Static38', 'Разрешить приложениям доступ к камере2']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Разрешить приложениям доступ к камере", auto_id="SystemSettings_CapabilityAccess_Camera_UserGlobal_Group_GroupTitleTextBlock", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Если доступ разрешен, вы можете с помощью параметров на этой странице разрешить или запретить доступ к камере для каждого конкретного приложения. Если доступ запрещен, приложения не могут использовать камеру. При этом доступ к ней остается у Windows Hello.'    (L344, T412, R785, B506)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Если доступ разрешен, вы можете с помощью параметров на этой странице разрешить или запретить доступ к камере для каждого конкретного приложения. Если доступ запрещен, приложения не могут использовать камеру. При этом доступ к ней остается у Windows Hello.', 'Если доступ разрешен, вы можете с помощью параметров на этой странице разрешить или запретить доступ к камере для каждого конкретного приложения. Если доступ запрещен, приложения не могут использовать камеру. При этом доступ к ней остается у Windows Hello.Static', 'Static39']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Если доступ разрешен, вы можете с помощью параметров на этой странице разрешить или запретить доступ к камере для каждого конкретного приложения. Если доступ запрещен, приложения не могут использовать камеру. При этом доступ к ней остается у Windows Hello.", auto_id="SystemSettings_CapabilityAccess_Camera_UserGlobal_Group_GroupDescriptionTextBlock", control_type="Text")
""" ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что разные настройки разбросаны по разным процессам (посмотрите у главного окна и у toggle элемента в Inspect.exe свойство ProcessId). Можно использовать объект класса Desktop без привязки к одному процессу.

```
params_window = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title=u"Параметры")
toggle = params_window.child_window(title=u"Разрешить приложениям доступ к камере", control_type="Button").wrapper_object()
```

Не уверен, что `params_window.dump_tree()` сработает, но можно попробовать. На данный момент метод `.dump_tree()` есть только у объектов класса WindowSpecification (в будущих релизах будет и у врапперов).

Comment: params_window.dump_tree() вот щас попробовал по разному - не видит. Попробовал также
`top_windows = Desktop(backend="win32").windows()`
видит "Доступ к камере для этого устройства".
К сожалению попытки взаимодействия приводят к ошибке AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ДоступккамередляэтогоустройстваButton'. Пока сделал быстро через костыль(распознавание картинки с переключетелем и клий по ней), но может придумаю нормальный вариант.